# React: How to reset state in custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component (AddSlides) which is using useUpload custom hook to upload files, in response the hook returns the download urls.  The hook is returning the same value when AddSlides component is re-rendered. To avoid this I am calling  reset method in useEffect of AddSlides component, but this is causing infinite loop, which is not surprising.

How do I reset the `downloadUrls` to empty after using it ? (See below reset method.

React Component addSlides.js

```
export default function AddSlides() {
  const [filesToUpload, setFilesToUpload] = useState([]);
  const { downloadUrls, setDownloadUrls, reset } = useUpload(
    filesToUpload,
    "AddSlides"
  );
  const [allUrls, setAllUrls] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
  setAllUrls([...allUrls, ...downloadUrls]);
  setFilesToUpload([]); // Resetting the files to empty

  //reset(); // Resetting the download urls, but this is causing an infinite loop.

}, [downloadUrls]);
return (<>//some code</>)
}
```

Custom hook useUpload.js

```
export default function useUpload(files, componentName = "") {
  const [downloadUrls, setDownloadUrls] = useState([]);

  const reset = () => {
    console.log("Setting download urls to empty");
    setDownloadUrls([]); // Resetting the value to empty array.
  };

  useEffect(() => {
   // Some code here
  }, [files, componentName]);

 return {
   downloadUrls,
   setDownloadUrls,
   reset,
 };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute reset  only if array length > 0

```
useEffect(() => {
  setAllUrls([...allUrls, ...downloadUrls]);
  setFilesToUpload([]); // Resetting the files to empty

  if (downloadUrls.length > 0) {
    reset()
  }

}, [downloadUrls]);
```